# Parsing PuTTY IRC Chat

Tags: python, irc

So I want to make a program to monitor an irc chat and send the user an email if their name is mentioned.

I'm wondering if it is possible to output the irc chat messages to a txt file? I'd like to use Python if possible.

The irc chat is a WeeChat. I'm not going to lie, I haven't been programming very long so I'm pretty clueless. I also had the idea of capturing the memory with Cheat Engine but that seems like a pretty terrible solution and I'd prefer if it can run on Linux. I also had a look at mIRC scripting which could work maybe?

UPDATE:
I can log the output of the chat using PuTTY logging feature, however the output is really hard to read and parse:

> 22[33m:[39m12[33m:[39m07    [1m[32m@[36mUSERNAMECENSORED[0m [32m| [39m"Two software developers are required, for[7C[34m│[1m[39m[32m@[0mUSER[58D[32m| [39mstudent summer positions, to write RESTful web   [34m│[1m[39m[32m@[0mUSER[32m| [39mservices in Python using the Django REST[9C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mUSER[6;20H[32m| [39mframework. The application being developed is a  [34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mdanielrb[7;20H[32m| [39mfinancial accounting system. Therefore, a[8C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mDee[56D
>   [32m| [39mknowledge of accounting is a distinct advantage. [34m│[1m[39m[34m [0meoghanc[60D[32m| [39mApplicants will be required to attend an[9C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mUser[10;20H[32m| [39minterview which will include technical[11C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mME[59D[32m| [39massignments. As well as training and experience, [34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mmtlight[60D
>   [32m| [39mthe[46C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0mshane
>   22[33m:[39m12[33m:[39m09    [1m[32m@[36mUser[0m [32m|    [39mpositions offer €400 per week for the successful [34m│[1m[39m[34m     [0msherkin[60D[32m| [39mcandidates."[37C[34m│[1m[39m[34m [0myensil22[33m:[39m17[33m:[39m03    [1m[32m@[36mUSER[0m [32m| [39mIt's only two months of work (approx) though :/  [34m│
>      [39m22[33m:[39m27[33m:[39m52  [1m[32m@

How would I parse this so I can tell when a user is mentioned and read the message as a string?

Comment: https://weechat.org/files/doc/devel/weechat_scripting.en.html

Comment: C seems to be the favoured language with this and it generally feels out of my depth. Can I use Python exclusively? Would this definitely be easier?

Comment: Did you actually open my link?

Comment: I did. I guess I can use Python then.